# Entity Framework Navigation Woes

Tags: entity-framework

I have `Business` and `BusinessProgram` declared as:

```
 public class Business : DbIdEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Address PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual Address PostalAddress { get; set; }

        public Guid OwnerKey { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Owner { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<BusinessProgram> BusinessPrograms { get; set;                   }

    }

public class BusinessProgram : DbEntity<Guid>
{
    public Business Business { get; set; }
    public ProgramType ProgramType { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpireDate { get; set; }
}
```

`DbIdEntity` and `DbEntity` are just base classes where the primary key (and an autonumbering `Id` field are declared.

When I query it using this query

```
foreach (Data.Business business in context.Businesses.Include(b => b.Owner)
                                                     .Include(b => b.PhysicalAddress)
                                                     .Include(b => b.Owner)
                                                     .Include(b => b.BusinessPrograms)
                                                     .OrderBy(b => b.Name))
```

I'm also using a convention that makes properties ending in "Key" the primary and foreign keys instead of the default "Id".

I get the error:

> "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'Data.Business' does not declare a navigation
>   property with the name 'BusinessPrograms'."

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I used `IEnumerable` instead of `ICollection`.  Using the correct navigation property type fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `IEnumerable` for my navigation type instead of `ICollection`.  Changing it to `ICollection` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had rather limited success with using base classes in the way you describe. I'd try "flattening" your model first, and getting it working like that. Then you could try re-introducing the base classes; you *might* be able to get that working too.

Here it looks as though `BusinessProgram` should contain a FK property called `BusinessProgram_BusinessId` if you want to use the default convention. Alternatively, you could give it a different name and use an attribute to override the default convention:

```
[ForeignKey("Business")]
public int BusinessId { get; set;}
```

Comment: I just tried flattening the class Hierarchy and it had no effect.

Comment: Adding the `ForeignKey` attribute also did nothing.

Comment: I did just notice that a table named "BusinessPrograms" was never created in the database.  I now suspect the problem is actually on the Context.

Comment: I corrected the problem in the context and the BusinessProgram table now shows up, however I still get the error trying to to Include it.

Comment: Found it!  I knew it had to be something simple enough to be easily overlooked.  I used IEnumerable for the navigation properties instead of ICollection.

Comment: Well done. Glad you found a solution. (Note that you are allowed to mark your own answer as the solution.)

Comment: There is a 2 day waiting period before it will allow you to mark your own answer as the solution.